# AutoCad Files Corrupted

Tags: autocad

I need to recover my autocad files. Every time I try to open a .dwg file it says "drawing file is not valid".

My HDD crashed and I restored my data using a recovery utility and since then my autocad files cannot open and giving the above messages.

Comment: The files are corrupt.  They cannot be repaired.  You need to restore the copies from your backup.  The recovery utility didn't recover the entire file.

Answer (score 2):

AutoDesk has some suggestions for repair here. http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/AutoCAD-File-Corruption.html

> If neither of the above options allow you to open the DWG, move on to the next set of steps. These steps can be tried one at a time. Be sure to stop and try to open the file after each one. If the file opens, there is no need to continue to the rest of the steps.
>
> 1. Open a blank DWG and run the RECOVER command. Select the problematic file. AutoCAD will attempt to recover the file and open it.
> 2. Open a blank DWG and run the RECOVERALL command. Select the problematic file. AutoCAD will attempt to recover the file and open it.
> 3. Open a blank DWG and run the INSERT command. Select the problematic file and see if it will insert. If it does, then run EXPLODE and select the inserted block. Run AUDIT and PURGE commands, and then use SAVEAS to create a new DWG.
> 4. Look in the same directory where the DWG resides and see if there is a BAK file of the same name. If so, rename the BAK extension to DWG and see if the file can then be opened.
> 5. Look in C:\Windows\Temp for files with an SV$ extension. If any exist with a similar name to the corrupted DWG file, then rename the extension to DWG and see if it can then be opened.
> 6. Go to your backup system and restore the file from a time before it became corrupted.

Note: Im kinda new to here. If I am supposed to do links and quotes differently let me know what I need to change.

Comment: I recommend you spend 5 minutes making it so people can read the answer.  It being in a quote block while correct makes I also extremely hard to read without scrolling said quote block which of course makes it difficult to read.  So format block and the answer since there are multiple steps involved.  You wanted reputation, you fixing this answer, is how that will happen.  I could format the answer for you, but you won't improve if I do that, and that means you won't accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Ramhound's probably right, the files are just corrupted, probably weren't fully recovered, maybe were fragmented & only got the first "chunk"...

Short of attempting to edit or repair the corrupted files, best bets would be:

- Best: restoring from a good backup
- Or: Attempt recovery again with a different program (`testdisk`, `scalpel`, etc)